# Targeting content to specific users

Tags: android, ios, mobile

There are two surveys I need to send to the users of my mobile app to complete. The first is sent to all users and is done right after they sign up.

The other survey however is sent to a select group of users a few months into their app usage. At the moment, I'm using Amazon Cognito for user pools and management so I would be able to identify the specific users this way.

As far as I know, I can't send an update to the app for the selected users only and include the new survey in it.

Maybe a viable idea is to include the survey hidden within the app and include a `0` or `1` in one of my user databases and include a check for that 0 or 1. Show the survey if it's a 1.

In general, how could I go about this?

Comment: Pretty mucha ll variations on that.  Include the survey, then decide whether or not to show it at runtime.  That can be based off of a setting, network call, etc.  Make the default to not show, so that it doesn't mysteriously disappear or accidentally get filled out because the network call failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest one of the following approaches using `Push Messages`:

#### Static solution

- You send a push to devices of your choice (pushes can be silent)
- User receives it and the application sets some key in `SharedPreferences`
- The app checks this Preference and sets this view to visible.

#### Dynamic Solution

- You send a push to devices of your choice (pushes can be silent)
- Push contains the whole survey data
- User receives it and the application sets some key in `SharedPreferences`
- The app checks this Preference and draws the survey dynamically